# How to create nested requests with sequelize between two tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have two tables in a sequelize backend I am building. The first table is `groups` and the second table is `members`. I want to:

In the end, I want to submit a an api request that contains a users Id. It will then grab all rthe records from the `members` table and for each record, grab the group which is referenced as a foreign key in the `members` table. I then want to return the group records to the frontend.

Is there a way to grab the foreign key records directly through the foreign key or do I need to make two requests?

Here is the code I have:

router:

```
router.route('/user_groups/:userId')
    .get(memberController.getUserMember)
```

Controller:

```
    getUserMember: (req, res) => {
        let group_list = [];
        let user_id = req.params.userId
        Member.findAll({ where: { userId: user_id } })
            .then((response) => {
                for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                    Group.findByPk(response[i]['groupId'])
                        .then((group) => {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(group))
                            group_list.push(group)
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log('Getting Group by Id error: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
                        })
                }
                console.log(group_list)
                res.status(200).send(data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Getting member by Id error: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
            })
    },
```

> the first request gets all of the member records containing the userId
>   the second request within the `then` function will cycle through the members and grab the 
>   groups for each record based on its Id through the foreign key
>   each of the records are that is returned from the group request is supposed to be stored in an array and then the array will be returned at the end....

The objects are not storing in the array and the array is not being returned. not sure what to do.

model member:

```
const Member = database.define(
    "member",
    {
        id: {type: seq.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        balance: {type: seq.FLOAT(9, 2), allowNull: true, defaultValues: '0.00', 
                validate: {isFloat: true}
        },
        open_tabs: {type: seq.INTEGER, allowNull: false, defaultValues: '0', 
                 validate: {isInt: true}
        },
        reference: {type: seq.STRING, allowNull: false, 
                 validate: {isAlphanumeric: true}
        },
        admin: {type: seq.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValues: false, 
              validate: {isIn: [['true', 'false']]}
        },
        active: {type: seq.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValues: false, 
              validate: {isIn: [['true', 'false']]}
        },
    },
    {
        createdAt:  seq.DATE,
        updatedAt:  seq.DATE,
    }
)


Member.belongsTo(Group)
Member.belongsTo(User)
```

model group:

```
const Group = database.define(
    "group",
    {
        id: {type: seq.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        name: {type: seq.STRING, allowNull: false, 
             validate: {}
        },
        description: {type: seq.TEXT, allowNull: true, 
                validate: {}
        },
//        icon: {type: seq.STRING, allowNull: false, 
//               validate: {}
//        },
        members: {type: seq.INTEGER, allowNull: false, 
                 validate: {isInt: true}
        },
        reference: {type: seq.STRING, allowNull: false, 
                 validate: {isAlphanumeric: true}
        },
        active: {type: seq.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValues: false, 
              validate: {isIn: [['true', 'false']]}
        },
    },
    {
        createdAt:  seq.DATE,
        updatedAt:  seq.DATE,
    }
)


Group.belongsTo(User, {as: "Host"})
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is the loop will complete before all the `Group.findByPk()` requests are completed and once loop completes the array is sent....but the array is still empty!

Map an array of the `Group.findByPk()` promises instead and use `Promise.all()` to do the `send()` after all those promises have resolved

Something like:

```
getUserMember: (req, res) => {

        let user_id = req.params.userId
        Member.findAll({ where: { userId: user_id } })
            .then((response) => {
                 const groupPromises = response.map(member=>{
                      return Group.findByPk(member['groupId']).then(groups=>{
                         member.groups = groups;
                         return member;
                      }); 
                 });
                 return Promise.all(groupPromises).then(data=>res.status(200).send(data))

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Something went wrong in one of the steps ' + JSON.stringify(err))
            })
    },
```

I'm assuming you want an array that includes the original member objects and have assigned the groups to each of those objects as property `groups`